# Back button in Finder occasionally disabled; always go up one step in hierarchy?

Tags: finder

The back button in Finder seems to only remember your own trail. I.e., when there is a folder higher up the hierarchy, but you did not visit it before you came to the current one, the back button will be disabled.

This means that when I open a Finder folder in an existing directory, the back button will not work. I would like it to function more like it does in Windows, so that the back button will always go up one step in the folder hierarchy. Is this possible on macOS Sierra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The back button behave the same way in Windows & Mac, it returns to where you last looked. If that was the only place you've been, it has no history.

You can test that in Windows by either selecting different locations from the sidebar shortcuts, or by opening a new window by right clicking a folder & selecting Open in new Window. It then will not have a History.

To navigate the hierarchy on Mac there are several options...

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>↑</kbd>  will climb the hierarchy,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>↓</kbd>  will descend it.
- From the Finder window toolbar, there is a hierarchy drop-menu - [image]
- Even without the toolbar visible,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  Click on the folder icon at the top of any window will drop the same menu.
- From the Path bar underneath, you can double click any item to open that point
  [image]

Comment: You're totally right, and I didn't know about the shortcuts or path bar. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't see a path bar on high sierra but cmd up did work.

Comment: @user1821961 - Path Bar toggle is in the View menu, or cmd/opt/p